# Rails Order before Group

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
allcomments = @comments.reverse_order
allcomments = allcomments.group("owner_id,owner_type")
```

I want to achieve something like this, but when rails execute the query. it will:

```
Comment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` ORDER BY `comments`.`id` DESC

Comment Load (3.5ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` GROUP BY owner_id,owner_type  ORDER BY `comments`.`id` DESC
```

Basically, I want to reverse order the comments so when they group it, it will be listing the latest comment instead of the first comment of each user.

Answer (score -3):

with rails 4.2.x following should work

```
Comment.group("owner_id, owner_type").order("id desc")
```

Comment: This does not work; The *order* is still moved to after the *group*